# Display data from database PHP OOP

Tags: php, database, oop, select

I'm pretty new to PHP OOP and i have to make a small web app for school.

One of the things i'm trying to do right is to select data from the database and display it in my front-end. I figured out how to display a single row but i wanted to display all rows in the table. How can i do that?

My function:

```
public function listJobs(){

        $myDb = $this->_controlPanel->getMyDb();
        $query = "Select * FROM jobs_offers";

        $result = $myDb->performQuery($query);


            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $this->title=$row['title'];
            $this->description=$row['description'];
            $this->category=$row['category'];
            $this->budget=$row['budget'];


}
```

My front-end:

```
<?php
header ('Content_type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

require_once ('utils/Autoloader.php');
session_start();

if (empty($myControlPanel)) {

    try {

    $myControlPanel = new classes_ControlPanel();

    $myControlPanel->setMyDb(new classes_DbManager());

    $myDbManager = $myControlPanel->getMyDb();

    }


    catch (Exception $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
}


$log = new classes_UserManager($myControlPanel);
$select = $log->listJobs();

$title = $log->title;
$description = $log->description;
$category = $log->category;
$budget = $log->budget; 

?>



<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

<h2>
<h2><?php echo $title; ?> </h2>
<h2><?php echo $description; ?> </h2>
<h2><?php echo $category; ?> </h2>
<h2><?php echo $budget; ?> </h2>

</div>
```

Comment: It's quite normal to use a while loop to iterate over single row fetches. You could also [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead of fetch_array to get an array of all rows

Comment: Can you please describe how can i do that in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the result will return an array of objects (PDO). You would want to return this array to your view. Or, in your case as a property of the object and not the single row like you did above.

Next, You want to use a foreach or while loop in the view. If you are using PDO (Php Data Object) you can do the following.

```
while($job = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
{
?>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <h2>
    <h2><?= $job->title; ?> </h2>
    <h2><?= $job->description; ?> </h2>
    <h2><?= $job->category; ?> </h2>
    <h2><?= $job->budget; ?> </h2>

</div>

<?php 
}
```

(Short Tags (`<?=$var?>`) are equivalent to `<?php echo $var?>`)

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp